# Can I allow users to install mdf file in a separate folder or drive during installation?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just finished a Windows Form app in C#. It uses a database, and the program runs perfectly in VS 2022. What I'm looking to do now is create an installation that will allow the user to select a separate folder or drive from where the main program is installed for the database.
For example if the program is installed into C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPrg I would then want the user to be able to, at one point during installation, select a different drive and/or folder and then the mdf file will be saved in that folder.

I created a Setup project under the program I wrote but it doesn't do this.

Is there a way to to it?c#

Comment: I don’t think you can (easily) do this in a setup program, but when the program is first run you can show a ‘set database location’ form that use a `FolderBrowserDialog` to set the location

Comment: Would also recommend making the default `%appdata%\program_name`